# discrete event simulators for C++

Tags: c++, performance, simulation, agent, discrete-space

I am currently looking for a discrete event simulator written for C++. I did not find much on the web written specifically in OO-style; there are some, but outdated. Some others, such as Opnet, Omnet and ns3 are way too complicated for what I need to do. And besides, I need to simulate agent-based algorithms capable of simulating systems of thousands of nodes.

Does anybody know anything suitable for my needs?

Comment: If you're comfortable with Python, you can try GarlicSim, which will let you do agent-based simulations. (I never tried it for thousands, but I don't think there will be a problem with it.)

Answer (score 4):

Others have good direct answers,  but I'm going to suggest an alternative.  If I understand you right, you want a system in C++ or such where you can post events that fire in the future, and code is run when those events fire.

I had a project to do like this, and I started out trying to write such an event system in C++ and then quickly realized I had a better solution.

Have you considered writing your program in behavioral Verilog?  That may seem strange to write software in a hardware description language, but a Verilog simulator is an event-based system underneath, and behavioral Verilog is a very convenient way to express events, timing, triggers, etc.  There is a free Verilog simulator (which is what I used) called Icarus Verilog.  If you're not using Ubuntu or some Linux distro with Icarus already in a package, building from source is straightforward.

Comment: please consider posting a link to an example of Verilog performing a simple DES example.  Thank you

Comment: @gatorback I'm not sure I've ever seem anyone else do this.  I'm sure they have, but the only example I know of is the aforementioned project I did, and I have no idea where I put that code.

Answer (score 4):

I would recommend having a second look to OmNet++. At first sight it may look quite complex, but if you look it into more detail you will find that most of the complexity is in the network add-on (the INET Framework). Unless you are going to do a detailed network simulation you do not need the INET.

Using OmNet++ core is not specially difficult and it may be simpler than other similar tools.

You may want to have a look to [an intro](https://docs.omnetpp.org/tutorials/tictoc/).

One of the things that makes OmNet++ attractive to me is its scalability. Is possible to run large simulations in a desktop. Besides, it is possible to scale the same simulation to a cluster without rewriting the code.

Answer (score 3):

You should consider [SystemC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SystemC), although I'd also recommend taking a second look at OmNet++.

Answer (score 2):

We use [SIMLIB](http://www.fit.vutbr.cz/~peringer/SIMLIB/) at my school. It is very fast, easy to understand, object oriented, discrete and continuous simulator. It might look outdated but it is still maintained.

Answer (score 1):

There is CSIM from [Mesquite Software](http://www.mesquite.com/) which supports developing models in C, C++ and Java. However, it is paid-commercial, AFAIK.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GBL library](http://www.gbresearch.com/gbl/Default.aspx). It's written in modern C++ and even supports C++0x features like move semantics and lambda functions. It offers several modeling mechanisms: synchronous and asynchronous event handlers, preemptive threads, and fibers. You can create purely behavioral, cycle accurate, and real-time models, or any mixture of those.

Comment: self prmotions is allowed if it fits the context its in (its an answer)